# Color code table cells based on percentiles

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I`m using the following MySQL query to output the **COUNT** of orders grouped by **DAYOFWEEK** over the different hours of the day, into an html table generated with php:

```
SELECT HOUR(`order_date`) as Hour,

Count(case when DAYOFWEEK(`order_date`) = 1 then `id` end) As Suday,
Count(case when DAYOFWEEK(`order_date`) = 2 then `id` end) As Monday,
Count(case when DAYOFWEEK(`order_date`) = 3 then `id` end) As Tuesday,
...

FROM `orders` WHERE 1

GROUP BY HOUR(`order_date`)
```

I`m getting the following output which is exactly what I should be getting:

```
Hour    Suday   Monday  Tuesday Wednesday
10        8      23       43       5
11       13      41       61      12
```

My question is how could I color code the cells based on it`s relative value over the total, so that for example the cells with higher values get colored red, while medium values get orange.

I was thinking of defining percentile ranges and giving each cell an attribute with it´s percent value, and then using an if (value_range == somethin%) then color...

Does anyone have a better idea for achieving this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function to check the value of the number and apply a different CSS class depending on its value.

Example PHP Function:

```
function checknumber() {
  if ( range >= '[number]' && <= '[number]' ) {
    $colorcode = 'red';
  }
  return $colorcode;
}
```

Use function:

```
<td class="<?php echo checknumber() ?>">[number]</td>
```

Define Style Rule:

```
.red {
  color:#F00;
}
```

Just repeat for as many colors and ranges you need.

Comment: Had to modify function but conceptually it works great